# Set 3x3 grid layout with swing

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to build a tic tac toe game with swing. Using grid layout its coming out to weird numbers of rows and columns and cant seem to get it to 3x3. What am I doing wrong? Should I just use a float layout and set positions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel);
    
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
    
    
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(grid);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        JButton button3 = new JButton();
        JButton button4 = new JButton();
        JButton button5 = new JButton();
        JButton button6 = new JButton();
        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        JButton button8 = new JButton();
        JButton button9 = new JButton();
    
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.add(button4);
        frame.add(button5);
        frame.add(button6);
        frame.add(button7);
        frame.add(button8);
        frame.add(button9);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you have already accepted @JustinCoding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671622/set-3x3-grid-layout-with-swing/69671671#69671671), I feel obliged to also answer since that answer doesn't really explain why your code did not produce your desired result.

Your problem is that you are adding an empty `JPanel` to the `JFrame` as well as your `JButton`s. Just remove that part of the code. Here is your corrected code. I commented the lines that need to be removed.

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
//        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//        frame.add(panel);

        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 3);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(grid);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        JButton button3 = new JButton();
        JButton button4 = new JButton();
        JButton button5 = new JButton();
        JButton button6 = new JButton();
        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        JButton button8 = new JButton();
        JButton button9 = new JButton();

        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.add(button4);
        frame.add(button5);
        frame.add(button6);
        frame.add(button7);
        frame.add(button8);
        frame.add(button9);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I run the code.

[image: screen capture of running Swing app]

### Explanation

Originally, in order to add components to a `JFrame`, you had to first call method [getContentPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane()) which returned a [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html) that you could add components to. `JFrame` is referred to as a [top level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and its *content pane* is the container for all the components that you add to it. The default *content pane* is a `JPanel` whose layout manager is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Hence no need to add your components to a `JPanel` and add that `JPanel` to the `JFrame`. You can add components directly to the `JFrame`. Just be aware that when you are adding components directly to a `JFrame`, you are actually adding them to a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`.

And since the *content pane* is a `JPanel`, you are free to also change its layout manager – as you have done in your code via this line:

```java
frame.setLayout(grid);
```

Note that you only need to set one of the dimensions in the `GridLayout` constructor. Here is a quote from the *javadoc* of that constructor.

> One, but not both, of rows and cols can be zero, which means that any number of objects can be placed in a row or in a column.

In other words, for your tic-tac-toe game, you need only set the columns to 3. That means that each row will contain no more than three columns so when you add nine buttons, `GridLayout` will ensure that they will be arranged in three rows of three columns each. Hence, for your tic-tac-toe board, you can use the following code.

```java
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0, 3); // zero rows and three columns
```

Comment: Thanks mate for pointing out that I didn't add any explanation. Fixed my answer.

Comment: I had to tweak the code provided originally to fit my suitings, just messed around with what i was provided first and made it work. This gives me a much deeper explanation and understanding though and I appreciate it allot. Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Thanks to @Abra  for pointing out that I had not added any explanation, because I was writing the answer in a bit hurry.

Follow these steps first:

Assign the layout to your panel like this: `panel.setLayout(grid);`

Then, add the panel to your frame like this: `frame.add(panel);`

Then, add all your widgets to the panel by replacing `frame` with `panel` where you're adding your Buttons.

And now, your JFrame bugged out a bit because you were also adding an empty JPanel to your Frame. I made you add the JPanel to the JFrame and assign the grid layout to the Panel just because I thought that a Tic-Tac-Toe game would include the showing of results of the game. So, you can simply use the remove() method to remove the JPanel and add the Results JPanel.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks so much! So can you not put child elements into a frame? You need a panel to contain them? Or can you set multiple panels in frame in the same manner? I dont understand the purpose of both